# Triangle Inequality for hitting time of Markov Chains

Tags: markov-chains

Given a finite, irreducible and aperiodic discrete time Markov chain on state space, $\{1, 2,\cdots, n\}$, define $h(i,j)$ to be the expected time for the first visit to $j$ from state $i$. Here we consider $h(i,i)$ to be the mean return time to $i$, so that $h(i,i) \geq 1$. Can we show the following
$$h(i,k) \leq h(i,j) + h(j,k),$$ for any $i,j,k$ in the state space?

Comment: This follows readily from the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I could not get it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_{ij}$ be the number of steps for a first passage from state $i$ to state $j$. Then $h(i,j)=\mathbf{E}T_{ij}$.

The proof is given, for example, in Lemma 4.1 in *Jeffrey Hunter. Stationary distributions and mean first passage times of perturbed Markov chains. Linear Algebra and its Applications, 410:217–243, 2005.* DOI 10.1016/j.laa.2005.08.005

I (almost) cite:

> The inequality $T_{ik}\le T_{ij}+T_{jk}$ follows from the sample path of a typical chain, since the chain will clearly take at least as many transitions (steps) to move from state i to state k via a first passage through state j
>   starting at state i as it will without making such a forced first passage through state j. The inequality for expectations follows upon taking expectations of the respective random variables (which are all well-defined proper random variables if the chain is irreducible.)

p.s.

The value $(T_{ij}+T_{jk})$ is also known as *commute time*.

In fact this inequality (graph-geodetic property) is more related to the graph theory. See

*Kirkland, S. J. and M. Neumann, “Group inverses of M-matrices and their applications,” CRC Press, 2012.*

*Chebotarev, P., Studying new classes of graph metrics, in: F. Nielsen and F. Barbaresco,
editors, Proceedings of the SEE Conference “Geometric Science of Information” (GSI-2013),
Lecture Notes in Computer Science, LNCS 8085 (2013), pp. 207–214.*

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, the result for sample paths. There could be multiple sample paths from $i$ to $k$ (some going via $j$, others not). We can have sample paths from $i$ to $k$, which do not go via $j$ which are longer than the ones which go via $j$.